# Instantiating Akka actors in a Play application with Subcut

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, akka, subcut

I have a Play 2.1 application.  I am also using Subcut for dependency injection, which is already set up and working for most parts of the application, except for one.

Say I have the following snippet of actor-related code:

```
import akka.actor._
import com.typesafe.plugin._
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka

class FoobarActor extends Actor {
   def receive = {
     // do stuff here
   }
}

object Foobar {
  val actor = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[FoobarActor])
}
```

Now, say I would like to inject some objects into each instance of the `FoobarActor` using Subcut.  This would require the actor class to extend `Injectable`, with the `BindingModule` passed into the constructor, like this:

```
import akka.actor._
import com.typesafe.plugin._
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka
import com.escalatesoft.subcut.inject.{Injectable, BindingModule}

class FoobarActor(implicit val bindingModule: BindingModule) extends Actor 
  with Injectable {

   val bazProvider = inject[BazProvider]
   val quuxProvider = inject[QuuxProvider]

   def receive = {
      // do stuff here  
   }
}
```

The question is: how is such an actor instantiated?

Typically, objects managed by Subcut are constructed in Subcut's configuration objects (i.e., objects that extend `NewBindingModule`), or in the case of Play's controllers, in the `Global` object (see [play-subcut on github](https://github.com/dickwall/play-subcut)).

What would I replace `Akka.system.actorOf(Props[FoobarActor])` with in order to override the instantiation of actors in order to pass in the binding module?

```
object Foobar {
  val actor = /* what goes here? */   
}
```

Comment: Did you already take a look at the Akka doc on DI ? http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.1/scala/actors.html#dependency-injection

Comment: I don't know about subcut, but it might be as simple as providing a `BindingModule` as constructor argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Roland mentioned, this should be as simple as just instantiating the actor with a constructor argument.  I wasn't sure the implicit would work with Akka's way of doing actor instantiation with constructor args but it seems to work okay.  The code should look something like this:

```
class FoobarActor(implicit val bindingModule: BindingModule) extends Actor 
  with Injectable {

   val bazProvider = inject[BazProvider]
   val quuxProvider = inject[QuuxProvider]

   def receive = {
      // do stuff here  
   }
}

object FoobarActor {
  def apply(implicit bindingModule:BindingModule) = {
    Akka.system.actorOf(Props(classOf[FoobarActor], bindingModule))
  }
}
```

Then, if you wanted to instantiate the `FoobarActor`, as long as you had an implicit `BindingModule` in scope, you could just do:

```
val ref = FoobarActor()
```

Comment: This seems to work with actors being created in the same local AkkaSystem only. BindingModule will most likely be not 100% serializable and immutable to allow for remote creation.